# a function similar to numpy.take that indexes the out parameter

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-indexing

In the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) of `numpy.take`, it is stated that `a` is indexed according to `indices` and `axis`, then the result is optionally stored in the `out` parameter. Does exists a function that perform the indexing on `out` instead? Using fancy indexing it would be something like:

```
out[:, :, indices, :] = a
```

Here I assume that `axis=2` but in my case I don't know the axis in advance.
A solution using 1d boolean masks instead of indices is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use swapaxes like so:

```
>>> A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> out = np.empty_like(A)
>>> I = [2,0,1]
>>> axis = 1
>>> out.swapaxes(0, axis)[I] = A.swapaxes(0, axis)
>>> out                                                                                                             
array([[[ 4,  5,  6,  7],                                                                                           
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],                                                                                           
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3]],                                                                                          

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],                                                                                           
        [20, 21, 22, 23],                                                                                           
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the `numpy` functions construct an indexing tuple when operating on a specified axis.

The code isn't particularly pretty, but is general and reasonably efficient.

```
In [700]: out = np.zeros((2,1,4,5),int)
In [701]: out
Out[701]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]],


       [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]])

In [702]: indices = [3,0,1]
```

Make an indexing tuple.  Start with a list or array for ease of construction, and then convert to `tuple` when indexing:

```
In [703]: idx = [slice(None)]*out.ndim
In [704]: idx[2] = indices
In [705]: idx
Out[705]: 
[slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, None, None),
 [3, 0, 1],
 slice(None, None, None)]
In [706]: out[tuple(idx)] = 10    
In [707]: out
Out[707]: 
array([[[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]]],


       [[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]]]])
```

It matches the `take`:

```
In [708]: np.take(out, indices, axis=2)
Out[708]: 
array([[[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]]],


       [[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
         [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]]]])
```

We can set more complex values, as long as we get the broadcasting right:

```
out[tuple(idx)] = np.array([10,11,12])[...,None]
```

I have also seen `numpy` functions that shift the axis of interest to a known location - either beginning or end.  Depending on the action it may require swapping back.

---

There are functions like `place`, `put`, `copyto` that provide other ways of controlling assignment (besides the usual indexing).  But none take an `axis` parameter like `np.take`.